# Mejorar query para evitar CTE anidados

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimización, cte

espero se encuentre muy bien.

Estoy separando una columna de algunas tablas, esta columna es un texto el cual tiene "niveles" separados por un guion medio, el texto de estas columnas es como el siguiente:

```css
* {
  border: black 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table class="tabla">

      <tr>

        <th>Campo1</th>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td>ax2589-mexico-celular-200x800-TDC-loyal-nivel1-ad-embeded</td>


      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td>ahj252189-mexico-webon-1200x2400-TDCDEBpay-nonsus-outlevel-print-onsites</td>

      </tr>


    </table>
```

El resultado esperado es añadir una columna por cada "nivel" en el texto, esto es cada palabra que está separada por un guion medio.

```css
*{
  border: blue 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table class="default">

  <tr>

    <th>Col1</th>

    <th>Col2</th>

    <th>Col3</th>
    
    <th>Col n...</th>

  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td>ax2589
</td>

    <td>mexico
</td>

    <td>celular
</td>
<td>texto n...
</td>

  </tr>

  
</table>
```

Logré el resultado utilizando CTE, una por cada "nivel", la query se ve de la siguiente forma:

```
WITH CTE1 AS(
SELECT * ,
    CASE
        WHEN 
(CHARINDEX('-',Campo1) - 1) < 1
        THEN Campo1
    ELSE
LEFT(Campo1,CHARINDEX('-',Campo1) - 1)
    END AS Col1
FROM  dbo.tabla), 

CTE2 AS 
(SELECT *,
    CASE
        WHEN
(CHARINDEX('-',Campo1) - 1) < 1
        THEN Campo1
    ELSE
LEFT(RIGHT(Campo1, CAST(LEN(Campo1) AS int) - (LEN(Col1) + 1)),   CHARINDEX('-',RIGHT(Campo1, CAST(LEN(Campo1) AS int) - (LEN(Col1) +1) -1 )))
    END AS Col2
FROM CTE1), 

CTE3 AS
(SELECT *,
    CASE
        WHEN
(CHARINDEX('-',Campo1) - 1) < 1
        THEN Campo1
    ELSE
LEFT(RIGHT(Campo1, CAST(LEN(Campo1) AS int) - (LEN(Col2) +LEN(Col1) + 1)),   CHARINDEX('-',RIGHT(Campo1, CAST(LEN(Campo1) AS int) - (LEN(Col2)+LEN(Col1) +1) -1 )))
    END AS Col3
FROM CTE2),

CTE4 AS
(SELECT *,
    CASE
        WHEN
(CHARINDEX('-',Campo1) - 1) < 1
        THEN Campo1
    ELSE
LEFT(RIGHT(Campo1, CAST(LEN(Campo1) AS int) - (LEN(Col2) +LEN(Col1)+len(Col3) + 1)),   CHARINDEX('-',RIGHT(Campo1, CAST(LEN(Campo1) AS int) - (LEN(Col2)+LEN(Col1) +LEN(Col3)+1) -1 )))
    END AS Col4
FROM CTE3)...
```

Cómo pueden ver, en la primera parte del CTE obtengo el primer nivel con la función LEFT, dentro de esta función CHARINDEX busca '-' y me dice su posición y le resto 1 para que me traiga el texto que quiero omitiendo el '-', la función está dentro de un CASE porque puede ser que algún registro venga vacío o no tenga el carácter '-'.

Después para el siguiente nivel ya tengo la Columna1, lo que hago es que dentro del CASE uso la función right, para obtener todo el texto de la derecha a partir del primer '-' restando el largo de la nueva columna 1, luego de nuevo utilizo LEFT cómo en le primer caso.

A cada nivel/columna le agrego la anterior y veo que si bien tengo el resultado que quiero, me compliqué bastante y considerando que son 9 columnas o más, corro el riesgo de obtener el error "expression services limit has been reached".

Gracias por leerme, ¿alguna opción que tenga para mejorar este desastre?.

Comment: ¿Cuál lenguaje usas para generar el html?

Comment: Tal vez [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43557422) te funcione, si usas SQL SERVER,, básicamente generas la función, `UFN_SEPARATES_COLUMNS`,  y por cada columna aplicas la consulta , `UFN_SEPARATES_COLUMNS(Columna, Indice , 'Separador')`

Comment: Muchas gracias @EduardoJaramilloLicea, sí parece una forma más civilizada de hacer la query, seguiré el ejemplo.